# Как удалить последние два символа в выведенном тексте, если он оканчивается на определенные символы

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Как можно сделать так - Если в выведенном тексте последние два символа - это ".0" , то эти два символа удаляются, а если последние 2 символа другие, то ничего не происходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки окончания строки удобно использовать метод `endswith`, а чтобы убрать последние символы, можно сделать **срез** строки

Пример:

```
text = '1234'

print(text.endswith('34'))
# True

print(text[:-2])
# 12
```

Comment: Добавил if и else, и все начало работать как и задумывалось. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @NikitaFedotov, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2):

вот так

```
text = text[:-2] if text[-2:] == '.0' else text
```